# How to print pdf file on button cilck

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintPage() {
            window.print("~/images/Dowload%20Re.JPG");
        }
    </script>

<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Print.JPG" Style="margin-top: 14px" Height="90px" Width="89px" OnClientClick="javascript:PrintPage();" />
```

Get the PDF file from the folder and on button click the file should be printed

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#generateprint").click(function(){

     window.location.href ="your link path here===just like http:8080//google.com;
 });
```

Bootstrap Button

```
<a href="#" id="generateprint" class="btn btn-default actions-icons"
                                    role="button" data-original-title="print"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true" alt="print"
                                    style="color: #0099ff;"></span> </a>
```